# capture h2 section with a specific word after the h2 section

Tags: jquery, regex

I have some html code that I am trying to capture something specific:

```html
<h2>Test</h2>

<p><strong>Test:</strong> ball, Admin, test</p>
```

when I use the following regex it only captures the h2 and second line..

```html
<h2>Test</h2>(?:\s*)
```

How would I capture that h2 section and the word **Admin** only using jquery?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is special about Admin that makes it what you want to return? Why not Test or ball or test?

Comment: Thank you @edemaine for the reply. I'm just trying to capture any word. It can be test, ball, admin, etc....

Comment: Do you mean you want to match the substring from `<h2>` until `Admin`?

Comment: yes capture <h2>Test</h2> with the word Admin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match everything between `<h2>Test</h2>` and `Admin`, use the following regular expression:

```
<h2>Test</h2>[^]*?Admin
```

`[^]` means "match any character", and `*?` means zero or more such characters, as few as possible.

Comment: this captures stuff after Admin. If i have content after <p><strong>Test:</strong> ball, Admin, test</p> its going to capture that as well. I'm only trying to capture <h2>Test</h2>

<p><strong>Test:</strong> ball, Admin,

Comment: The regex above will not match beyond Admin, if you're matching it against an HTML string. I get the impression that you're maybe using this regex in some context that you didn't specify? Could you clarify how you're using the regex?

Comment: I got it to work. I accidentally had . in front of *. Thank you for your help :)